# Consulta eloquent Laravel 10 Problema en el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Estoy intentando mostrar en la vista solamente los usuarios cuyo `group_id` sea igual a 1 y que en el campo `verificacion` tenga 'NULL'.
En el código de abajo de mi controlador no genera ningún error a priori, pero no muestra el usuario el cual pertenece al `group_id` 1 y tiene `verificacion` 'NULL'.

```php
public function vistaProfes()
{
    // Verificar si el usuario actual cumple con los criterios de profesor
    if (auth()->user()->groups_id != 1 || auth()->user()->verificacion !== 1) {
        // Redirigir a la página de login
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    $solicitudes = SolicitudProfesor::with(['user' => function ($query) {
        &query->where('groups_id', 1)
             ->whereNull('verificacion');
             }])
             ->orWhere(function ($query) {
             $query->doesntHave('user')
             ->whereNull('verificacion');
                 })
    ->get();

    return view('profes', compact('solicitudes'));
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Saludos, por lo que comentas deberías usar `&&` en vez de `||`  y `auth()->user()->groups_id != 1 || auth()->user()->verificacion == NULL` en tu validación.

Comment: Te aconsejo que uses `whereHas`

Answer (score 0):

hola gente al final lo resolvi de esta manera espero que les sea util!

```
public function vistaProfes()
    {
        // Verifico si el usuario actual cumple con los criterios de profesor
        if (auth()->user()->groups_id != 1 || auth()->user()->verificacion !== 1) {
            // Redirigir a la página de login
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        
    //Aca simplefique la consulta y me dio lo que realmente queria 

            $solicitudes = SolicitudProfesor::where('groups_id', 1)
                                            ->where('verificacion', 0)
                                            ->get();
        
        
        return view('profes', compact('solicitudes'));
    }
```